# Laravel Delete and Update

Tags: php, laravel

I created a Post and a Get Request, Looks like this:

```
public function getAllCustomer()
{

    $customer = \App\model\Customer::get();
    return $view = View::make('test')->with('customer', $customer);
}

public function addNewCustomer(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'Title' => 'required',
        'Name' => 'required|max:255'

    ]);

    return \app\model\Customer::create($request->all());
}
```

So I can read all the data and create some new one, but now I want to delete them and/or update them, I couldnt find something really helpful, I would be very thankful for some help!

Comment: Check this article: [Laravel Hive - Laravel 5.6 CRUD tutorial example](https://laravelhive.com/laravel-5-6-crud-tutorial-example/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for updating you can define a route like this

```
Route::put('customer/{customer}' , 'CustomerController@update');
```

you should define a method_field('put') in your form
and create a function called update in your controller

```
pulblic function update (Request $request , Customer $customer){
   // validate you inputs
   $validatedData = $request->validate([
    // validation rules goes here
   ]);
   //  better approach would be using form requests
   $customer->update($validatedData);
}
```

to update the fields that you want to be updated, you have to add them to $fillable array in your customer model, read about [Mass Assignment] [1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment) in laravel and that because all Eloquent models are protected against mass-assignment by default.

for delete :
route:

```
Route::delete('customer/{customer} , 'CustomerController@destroy');
```

a function for deleteing customer in your controller

```
public function destroy (Customer $customer){
  $customer->delete();
}
```

and add method_field('delete') to your form

**Form example**:

```
    <form  action="{{url("customer/{$customer->id}")}}" 
method="post">
         {{method_field('delete')}}
        //Html Elements Here
     </form>
```

after you get familiar with routes and controller you can make benefits of using

```
Route::resource('customer','CustomerController');
```

which will create all necessary route for you

**Edited**: please note that {customer} in route should be the id of the Customer you want to update or delete

**Update:** passing request->all() to update or create is not a good practice so i changed it with validated data, here is a link for laravel [Form Request Validation](https://form%20requests%20valiadtion%20https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation)

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean with add a method field ('delete') in your form? Currently Im getting MethodNotAllowedException.

Comment: look at the delete route i've created is not post or get it's delete but html forms only support post and get methods so in blade you can add a method field like this method_field('delete') and that will tell laravel this is not a post it is a delete and laravel will know that you are calling a delete route

Answer (score 0):

So to do delete you do in routes

```
Route::delete('customer/{customerId}', 'CustomerController@delete')
```

In controller

```
public function delete(Request $request, $customerId)
{
    $user    = $request->user();

    $customer= $user->customers()->find($customerId);
    $customer->delete();

    return back();
}
```

To do update in routes

```
Route::patch('customers/{customerId}', 'CustomerController@update')
```

In controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $customerId)
{
    $user    = $request->user();

    $customer= $user->customers()->find($customerId);
    $customer->update($request->all());

    return back();
}
```

More info as always in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#updates