# Update and delete -- I can't update and delete data from database in Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am using a form to submit my request to update and delete my data from database but I am unable to do so.

I have tried using different methods but I could not solve this problem. I am using Laravel 5.4.36 for this project.

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    Student::where('id', $id)->update(['first_name' => 'vks', 'last_name' => 'pok']);
}

public function destroy(Request $id)
{
    $student=Student::find($id);
    $student->delete();
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/student/about', 'BksController@about');
Route::get('/student/service', 'BksController@Services');
Route::get('create','BksController@create');
Route::post('create','StudentController@create');
Route::get('search','BksController@search');
Route::post('search','StudentController@show');
Route::get('/update','BksController@update');
Route::put('update','StudentController@update');
Route::get('/delete','BksController@delete');
Route::delete('/delete','StudentController@destroy');
Route::resource('student', 'StudentController');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Blade Template for the destroy form:

```
@include('student.commonlayout')

<div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
  <h1>DeleteData</h1>
  <hr>
  <form method="post" action="{{url('delete')}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Id" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Blade template for the update form:

```
@include('student.commonlayout')

<div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3'>
  <h1>update Data</h1>
  <hr>
  <form method="post" action="{{url('update')}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="id" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your id" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter last Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

When updating, I receive the following error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251

When deleting, I receive a similar error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  When asking questions, make sure to outline exactly the problem you are having and the expected output.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on how to ask good questions that will get good answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Delete and Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709151/laravel-delete-and-update)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a POST method in any of your delete or update routes.

```
  Route::get('/update','BksController@update');
  Route::put('update','StudentController@update');
  Route::get('/delete','BksController@delete');
  Route::delete('/delete','StudentController@destroy');
```

When you click button in your form, it does a HTTP post. So change your routes to `Route:post(...)` to match accordingly.

Comment: i put  @method('put') but it is displayed as if it is a paragraph in my browser view in http://127.0.0.1:8000/update.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Route::resource(...)` will create the routes with HTTP request methods `DELETE` for the `destroy` action and `PUT` for the `update` action. This means you have to use these methods when submitting the form.

Unfortunately, HTML forms do not support `PUT` or `DELETE`. This is why Laravel uses a special hidden input called `_method` which is supposed to contain the correct method. The form itself is supposed to be sent via `POST`. This is what your update form should look like (fields and other markup ommitted):

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('update') }}">
  @method('put')
  {{ csrf_field() }}

  <!-- Your fields here -->
</form>
```

The directive `@method('put')` will generate the following html `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">`.

You can read more about this topic in [the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing).

Comment: +1, also then he'll need to get the ID with `$request->input("id")`, it won't be directly accessible with `$id` parameter.

Comment: i put @method('put') but it is displayed as if it is a paragraph in my browser view in 127.0.0.1:8000/update.